# Index based Data structure in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I have some values (:a , :a , :b , :c , :f , :f) which I want to store in a unique index based Data structure, which I can later iterate over to get my values.

Can any one please let me know which is the simplest way ?

E.g

1. :a
2. :a
3. :b
4. :c
5. :f
6. :f

LATER,

Iterate on the DATA STRUCTURE based upon, the INDEX, to get my values

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like a `List<String>`?

Comment: Yes But If a unique Index (simple iterating number is STORED seperately), it will be good.

Comment: Indexes don't need to be stored. That's the whole point. Maybe you mean a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could use a `List<String>` like so

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> al = Arrays.asList(":a", ":a", ":b",
      ":c", ":f", ":f");
  for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d. %s%n", 1 + i, al.get(i));
  }
}
```

Output is (note: the index starts at 0, so I added one above to get your requested output)

```
1. :a
2. :a
3. :b
4. :c
5. :f
6. :f
```

Comment: How can I add the values dynamically in a loop ?

Comment: `List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); for (char i = 'a'; i < 'g'; i++) { al.add(":" + i);}`

Comment: Hii !! I was wrong. In case the values are same, the reletive key should also be the same

1. :a
1. :a
2. :b
3. :c
4. :f
4. :f

Comment: @NomanK That's a very different question. I suggest you post another.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array`, arrays is an object that can have a lot of values, that you access with a index.

Example:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 11;
int c = 12;
int d = 13;

int value[] = { a, b, c, d };


//syntax access is value[elementPosition], you have 4 elements inside, positions begins on zero, so you must use 0, 1, 2 and 3 (total of 4).

//value[0] will result 10
//value[1] will result 11
//value[2] will result 12
//value[3] will result 13
```

You could just use:

```
int value[] = { 10, 11, 12, 13 };
int[] value = { 10, 11, 12, 13 };
```

Or you can create an array and pass it values later:

```
int[] value = new int[4] // 4 = num of values will be passed to this array

value[0] = 10;
value[1] = 11;
value[2] = 12;
value[3] = 13;

value[4] = 14 // this will result IndexOutOfBoundsException, because it will be the 5th element.
```

You can do the same for String, float, etc.